# rearrange column's elements and display count

Tags: unix, shell, awk

i have text file like this:

```
i
am 
fine
how
are
you
what
i
how
are
```

i need an output like below:

```
i : 2
am : 1
fine : 1
how : 2
are : 2
you : 1
what : 1
```

there can be many repititions of the words:
how could i do this using a shell script or an awk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sort | uniq -c
```

It sorts it and the count is by default before the line. Would that work?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ count[$1]++ }
    END { for (a in count) printf("%s : %d\n", a, count[a]) }' filename
```

`awk` has associative arrays, and all the variables are initialized to 0, so the above works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

@OP, if you want to preserve the order

```
awk ' { a[$0]++; d[NR]=$0 }
END{
 for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){
    if( ! (d[i] in p)  ){
        print a[d[i]],d[i]
        p[d[i]]
    }
 }
} ' file
```

output

```
$ ./shell.sh
2 i
1 am
1 fine
2 how
2 are
1 you
1 what
```

Answer (score -1):

In Perl:

```
perl -le'while (<>){ chomp; $seen{$_}++}; print map { $_ . " : " . $seen{$_} } keys %seen'
```

Comment: Oops I forgot the increment!  (Several months later...) :)